# any php library with german to english dictionary translation?

Tags: php, translation

are there any good libraries out there? I tried using google translate API but it serves only limited number of requests per minute. Has anbody used UNI leipzig service for translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is microsoft's web solution:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638310.aspx

here is a php wrapper for the google translate api:
http://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/